# How do I access a function from another script (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to access a function from another script, I want to make a health bar script but it can't access the script any way I try (I have a lot of same named game objects so find won't work that smoothly).

I tried absolutely everything I could find, like defining the child of my object and getting the script component, but still the `healthBarScript` is `null`.

Here's everything I tried:

HealthScript

```
public float maxHealth = 100;
    public float health = 100;
    [SerializeField] private HealthBarScript hbScript;
    public GameObject child;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        child = transform.Find("/Customer/Background/Foreground").gameObject;
        hbScript = child.GetComponent<HealthBarScript>();
        hbScript.updateHealthBar(maxHealth, health);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        if(health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            hbScript.updateHealthBar(maxHealth, health);
        }

    }
    public void takeDamage(float damage)
    {
        health = health - damage;
    }
```

HealthBarScript:

```
public class HealthBarScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Image healthBar;
    public GameObject fg;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        healthBar = gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       
    }

    public void updateHealthBar(float maxHealth, float currentHealth)
    {
        healthBar.fillAmount = currentHealth / maxHealth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [GetComponentInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) to find and get a reference of the component in child game objects.

So it will be:

```
hbScript = GetComponentInChildren<HealthBarScript>(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the "/" before customer.